# How to run python flask api on Docker windows container?

Tags: python, docker, flask, dockerfile, windows-container

I have python flask code which i want to run in windows container. The OS that i'm using is windows 10.

My application runs well, But how can i dockerize my application?

```py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
   return 'Hello World’

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/) on how to deploy a flask server.

Comment: This question is very broad and I suspect a lot of people have written blog articles on this topic.

Comment: sure, I have created an app. Thanks....

Comment: Someone please suggest some blogs which explains how to dockerize flask app in windows container and the Dockerfile